# Tar a list of files without their directory structure

Tags: linux, centos, tar

Say I do this:

`tar cvf allfiles.tar $(<mylist.txt)`

and *mylist.txt* contains this:

```
/tmp/lib1
/tmp/path2/lib2
/path3/lib3
```

How to tar the files so the tarball contains just

```
lib1
lib2
lib3
```

with no directory structure at all?

---

The `-C` of `--directory` options are usually recommended ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695881/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-without-retaining-the-directory-structure), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939982/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-of-files-and-folders-without-including-the-directory-it)), but there are multiple directories so this doesn't work. Also, `--xform` looks like it requires a fixed pattern ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692619/1938889)) which we do not have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--xform` argument takes any number of `sed` substitute expressions, which are very powerful. In your case use a pattern that matches everything until the last `/` and replace it with nothing:

```
tar cvf allfiles.tar --xform='s|.*/||' $(<mylist.txt)
```

Add `--show-transformed-names` to see the new names.

Note, this substitution applies to all filenames, not just those given on the command line, so, for example, if you have a file `/a/b/c` and your list just specifies `/a`, then the final filename is just `c`, not `b/c`.  You can always be more explicit and provide an exact list of substitutions, eg in your case

```
--xform='s|^tmp/path2/||;s|^tmp/||;s|^path3/||'
```

Note, the initial `/` will be removed by tar (unless you use `-P`) so the above expressions are missing it. Also, the list of directories has to be sorted so the longest match is done first, else `tmp/path2/` won't match as `tmp/` has already been removed.  But you can automate the creation of this list, eg:

```
--xform="$(sed <mylist.txt 's|[^/]*$||; s|^/||; s:.*:s|^&||;:' | sort | tr -d '\n')"
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need all with one parameter. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `tar`, you can use `-C` whenever and as often as you like, with immediate effect.

```
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── aaa
├── 2
│   └── bbb
└── 3
    └── ccc



# Caveat: the directory change is always relative to directory tar is using *at
# that time*, so the following doesn't work:
$ tar -cf foo.tar -C 1 aaa -C 2 bbb -C 3 ccc  
tar: 2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ tar -cf foo.tar -C 1 aaa -C ../2 bbb -C ../3 ccc

$ tar tf foo.tar
aaa
bbb
ccc


# You can avoid the special case for the first directory by always specifying
# an absolute path:
$ tar -cf foo.tar -C $(pwd)/1 aaa -C $(pwd)/2 bbb -C $(pwd)/3 ccc



# Now let's create that automatically from your file:
$ cat mylist.txt
/tmp/1/aaa
/tmp/2/bbb
/tmp/3/ccc

$ while read -r line; do printf '-C %s %s ' $(dirname "$line") $(basename "$line") ; done < mylist.txt
-C /tmp/1 aaa -C /tmp/2 bbb -C /tmp/3 ccc 

# That looks about right. Let's use it in our tar command:
$ tar -cvf foo.tar $(while read -r line; do printf '-C %s %s ' $(dirname "$line") $(basename "$line") ; done < mylist.txt)
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you. I chose the other answer only because with a single parameter it can do what I'm looking for.