# tar files identified by wildcard but discarding file structure

Tags: files, tar, directory-structure

I tar files using

```
tar -czvf pngs.tar.gz folder*/*.png
```

which tars the correct files but maintains the file structure, but I want everything without folders inside the tar-ball. How do I do that?

File structure as illustration:

- folder0001:

  - 0001.abc.png
  - 0001.dfg.png
  - ...
- folder0087:

  - 0087.fje.png
  - 0087.gho.png
- ...

  - ...
- otherfolder

  - ...
- ...

Comment: you could use -C to change to the dir when making the tar, or use --strip-components during extraction (on gnu tar)

Comment: following [Tar a list of files without their directory structure](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317853/tar-a-list-of-files-without-their-directory-structure)  I ended up using `tar -cvzf pngs.tar.gz --transform='s/folder[0-9]*\///' folder*/*.png`